# Simplifying the Generalized Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

Let $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$ be symmetric positive-definite real $n\times n$ matrices. We want to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem
$$
\Sigma_1V=\Lambda\Sigma_2V,
$$
where $\Lambda$ is the generalized eigenvalue matrix and $V$ the generalized eigenvector matrix.

I am particularly interested in computing the **eigenvalues**. Also, I am looking for a *c-friendly solution*. I am going to use the **GNU Scientific Library (GSL)**, and thus I don't want to do unnecessary computations. That's why I ask here. Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT**

By applying Cholesky decomposition on $\Sigma_2$, we have $\Sigma_2=LL^\top$, where $L$ is a lower triangle matrix. Then, the desired eigenvalues can be found by solving a "simpler" eigenvalue problem. That is, the desired eigenvalues coincide with the eigenvalues of the following matrix
$$
L^{-1}\Sigma_1(L^\top)^{-1}.
$$

**What would be a good programming practice here?** Should I first compute $L$ (using Cholesky), and after that conducting the triple multiplication, and finally find the eigenvalues (using a GSL solver)? Or is there any simplifications that would make the total computation cost smaller?

Comment: Why does not `gsl_eigen_gensymm` suit your goals?

Comment: Well, it does suit indeed! I only found out a few hours after asking... I should have been looking for that a bit more carefully and patiently... Thanks @uranix!